# SVG Long Shadow

Tags: html, svg, sass

So I've got this svg of a code symbol on my website and I want to add a long shadow to the svg. I've tried using filter: drop-shadow() but that only allows for one offset, I'm looking for the same feature as box-shadow where I can add multiple offsets to make a long shadow.

I'm using Sass for my styling and have made a function that makes long shadows for boxes and then is called with a mixin but unfortunately I can't find how to do the same with svg.

Anyone got any work arounds?

Comment: Probably best if you a) show us your drop shadow attempt and then b) give us a picture of what you want it to look like instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you mean by a long shadow - but I'm assuming that you're looking for an extrusion? You can do that by doing multiple offsets and in a SVG filter - and then referencing that filter from CSS.

```css
.icon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  filter: url(#long-shadow);
}
```

```html
<img class="icon"  src="https://material.io/tools/icons/static/ic_icons_192px_light.svg">



<svg width="0px" height="0px">
<defs>
  <filter id="long-shadow" x="0%" width="130%" y="0%" height="130%">
    <feOffset dx="1" dy="1" result="layer1" in="SourceAlpha"/>
     <feOffset dx="1" dy="1" result="layer2" />
      <feOffset dx="1" dy="1" result="layer3" />
       <feOffset dx="1" dy="1" result="layer4" />
        <feOffset dx="1" dy="1" result="layer5" />
         <feOffset dx="1" dy="1" result="layer6" />
          <feOffset dx="1" dy="1" result="layer7" />
              
  <feMerge>

    <feMergeNode in="layer1"/>
    <feMergeNode in="layer2"/>
        <feMergeNode in="layer3"/>
            <feMergeNode in="layer4"/>
                <feMergeNode in="layer5"/>
                    <feMergeNode in="layer6"/>
                        <feMergeNode in="layer7"/>
                            <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
  </feMerge>
  </filter>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thanks! Is there a way I can loop the creation of the offsets in js as my extrusions are quite long.

Comment: Okay I managed to loop it but it makes my site lag like hell... any alternative?

Comment: I made the filter more efficient by re-using the initial SourceAlpha (see new version) - that may help. The only alternative is to draw the shadow explicitly as as separate shape - this is the only way to do it with a dropshadow/filter.